# winforms custom control moves when compiling

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms app I align the controls so that the look like picture 1. When I compile, a custom control resizes and repositions itself which is an undesirable effect. How can I stop this from happening. Autosize is set to false on everything.

Before compile: Correct.
[image: before]

After compile: Incorrect.
[image: after]

The picture is misleading. The form stays the same dimensions. It's the custom control that is changing size.

Comment: It's impossible to tell exactly why that happens without seeing how the form creates/uses the user control.

Comment: Both pictures are at design-time.

Comment: This is a custom control that you've written yourself? If so, then anything is possible if it is written incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, controls resizing itself to the size of even 0,0 after every rebuild, wich got quite annoying after a while.
After searching through SO i found the solution in Rich his reply on a question similair to this: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1909226/1951720)

Basicly, when you set your Form's ***Autoscale*** property to ***None***, this problem will dissapear.

Enjoy :)

Comment: same issue.
but my case solved by autoscale to Font.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Anchor property of the textbox or label in the custom control